# Google Analytics doesn't show the correct landing page for my Facebook ads

Tags: google-analytics, facebook, links

Most of the visitors to my site are supposed to come from an external link with URL `example.com/en/var` from Facebook ads but Google Analytics shows that most of the landing page is `example.com/var` without `en` which is the prefix for English version of my site.
Am I missing something to configure Google Analytics? Or is Facebook sending the visitors to the wrong URL (by the preview page of the Facebook ads the URL is set correct with the prefix en)?

Comment: Do you have a redirect in place?
Are you using campaign tags on your destination email?

Comment: Please respond to the requests for clarification so that your question can be answered.